# 1 user can add 1 review for one hotel/motel/object [Node.js & MongoDB]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am building a project in Node.js (using Express and MongoDB(with Mongoose) where logged-in users can add reviews to hotels. However I don't want a user to add more than one review to a hotel (will be able only to edit or delete the existing).

So I decided to create a middleware function which is going to check if the logged-in user ID matches any of the hotel's reviews author's ID. If true, I will redirect the user back (of course adding flash message that the user has already added a review to the hotel ... etc etc). But it is not going very tidy for me.

In the hotel's model I have implement reviews property where I am storing only the referring review's ids

```
middleWare.noRepeat = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
      Hotel.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundHotel){
          if(err){
              console.log(err);
          } else{
             foundHotel.reviews.forEach(function(review){
                 Review.findById(review, function(err, foundReview) {

                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    } else{
                        if(foundReview.author.id.equals(req.user._id)){
                            res.redirect("back");
                            //flash message to be implemented
                        } else {
                            next();
                        }
                    }
                 });
             });
          }
      });
  }  
};
```

This code doesn't work well for me. I am getting an error saying "Can't read author property of null". I think that this part here:

```
foundHotel.reviews.forEach(function(review){
                 Review.findById(review, function(err, foundReview) {
```

might be a problem. I am using **review** as the id argument of the **findById** method because in the hotel's model as I mentioned I have reviews property which is an array that stores the related review's ids. It looks something like this:

```
    reviews: [ ObjectId("53f3ada529cb20192ra35c8h"),
 ObjectId("12f3d6afdcd3cd15ktbcf8e98i"),
 ObjectId("1234abcdef56ghijk")]
```

Lastly I am only beginner with 2.5 months experience in this. This is my first project and I am sorry if this question looks stupid to you. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested async calls, `Hotel.findById()` & `Review.findById()`,may cause a problem here. If you are open then let me suggest you an alternative approach using mongoose [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). I assume your Hotel schema looks like this:

```
{
   // some properties
   reviews: [Schema.Types.ObjectId]
}
```

You can change your Hotel schema to look something like this:

```
{
    // some properties
    reviews: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'review'    //refer your review schema here    
    }]
}
```

The benefit of doing this is: 
**You can find Hotel by id and [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) reviews, completely avoiding `Review.findById()`.**

So your middleware should look something like this:

```
middleWare.noRepeat = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
      Hotel
        .findById(req.params.id)
        .populate('reviews')
        .exec(function(err, foundHotel){
          if(err){
              console.log(err);
          } else{
             foundHotel.reviews.forEach(function(review){
                 // this time the review variable
                 // will contain complete review object,
                 // rather than containing only id
                 if(review.author.id.equals(req.user._id)){
                     return res.redirect("back");
                     //flash message to be implemented
                 }
             });
             return next();
          }
      });
  }  
};
```

Hope the answer helps you!

Comment: Yes Ankit it helped me a lot more than you think. You saved me time reinventing the populate method as I see hahaha. Exactly what I needed mate! Thanks for helping me. Learned something new today. Have a good day.